# Quantify actual vs theoretical network throughput

Tags: ethernet, throughput, speed

I'm wondering whether there exists a standard which network throughput could be judged upon. For example: a 100 Mbit/s link has an actual throughput of 80 Mbit/s that given point in time and with whatever set of protocols -- has any article or paper ever written: "80% is a good percentage for actual throughput" (or something to that effect)?

I've made my own measurements on some networks, but I'd like something to lean on other than my own opinion on what percentage is good or bad.

I hope this isn't too unclear; thanks!

Comment: I sense that you're trying to address a perceived network performance problem.   If so, you're really barking up the wrong tree with this question.   The best thing you can do is fire up iperf and make some measurements around expected throughput; if you have delay, packet loss or excessive jitter, then solve those problems.

Comment: There is no problem with the network I've measured, and I did use Iperf to measure the expected throughput. The problem is that when I give my assessments, I only have my own opinion on what's good or bad to go on. I'm wondering whether there are some papers or articles who address this.

Comment: If all you care about are [references for articles or papers](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255/recommendations-and-polls), then the question is off-topic.  If you're simply trying to find out whether 80% of capacity is typical, that question is on-topic.  Please consider rephrasing the question, if you'd like to get more input from other users.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, but 30% is good.

Long answer: **Everything** determines network throughput. I have done lots of stress testing on network equipment, primarily cisco. Results of my tests have shown some routers/switches with 100mbps interfaces that achieve around 25mbps in actual throughput, and I have seen 1gbps interfaces achieve speeds of up to around 987mbps. The performance will vary significantly based on characteristics of the traffic as well. If your throughput on a given interface exceeds 30% of the line rate, I would recommend upgrading the link/interface.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is it is important to know the hardware running the network and the overall design of the network itself to be able to determine expected throughput?